# MVC 5 - IdentityDbContext Calling Database.Exists On Every Page

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I've developed a MVC5 application. The database context derives from `IdentityDbContext`.  When I'm creating an instance of the database context and it calls to the base class, the `IdentityDbContext` is calling a `Database.Exists()` method.

Is there anyway I can stop this because when a user hits the login page, it requires a `UserManager` which requires a `DbContext` and so it queries the database to see if the database exists.

In any case on every page, my controller constructors sets this `UserManager` so this query is always being sent.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't unique to ASP.Net Identity; any page that uses ANY context from Entity Framework is going to call this method.... It's not a SQL query though; is this specific method causing some sort of performance issue?

Comment: This seems like overkill and what would be the downside to not have it?  I could see it being required if there was a DbInitializer.

Comment: It is a sql query, though.  `IF db_id(N'DatabaseName') IS NOT NULL SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'DatabaseName'`   This was output from implementing the `IDbCommandInterceptor` interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging I figured out why the query was being called.  For some reason, I was thinking that `throwIfV1Schema` was defaulted to false.  This is one of the overloads in the `IdentityDbContext` constructor which is defaulted to true and causes the `DBContext.Exists()` to be called every time a new instance of `IdentityDbContext` is created.